# A tough java garbage-collection turning for me, I am really stuck in it

Tags: java, garbage-collection

*Background:*

I hava a java Web project(using springMVC redis activeMQ etc. JDK version: 1.7.0_79 64 bits) in opensuse13.1 64bitsOS.

Tomcat Bootstrap option is :-Xms8192m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

GC algorithm : ParallelGC

*Situation:*

When I check this project by jstat:

```
jstat -gcutil 16782 1s 1000
  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
  ......
  0.00  14.00  74.53  95.53  24.44 199887 11634.417   167  931.848 12566.265
  0.00  14.00  74.53  95.53  24.44 199887 11634.417   167  931.848 12566.265
  0.00  14.00  74.53  95.53  24.44 199887 11634.417   167  931.848 12566.265 
  ......
```

I found that full gc using too much time(5.57s per every STW)，so I want to do some optimization for this.

This project can run for really long time and it seemed there is no memory leak(I observe memory occupation for 60days, it will not go to memory out).

At First, I think may be some tempary obect allocate too frequently.

So I dumped two bin file: one is 75%old space, one is after gc 57%old space, I compared these two file by MAT using keep unreachable mode and unkeep mode.

The eden space is increased fast，every minor gc will moved some object to old space.

After analysis, I found some interesting things that confused me very much:
It seems that these objects moved to old space is not used by my codes, they are all LinkedHashMap entry, and the entry key is a class file， the value is a java.io.ExpiringCache$Entry object.

I track the GC path, it also not used by my codes( it used by java.io.File object and ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]].)

unreachable objects:
[image]
LinkedHashMap entry:
[image]
path2gc
[image]

*Problem*:

What's the goal of  LinkedHashMap entry and java.io.ExpiringCache$Entry?

Why  eden space is increased so fast?

Is it possible to make minor gc swept these unreachable objects but full gc?

Please give me some help, Thanks very much.

Comment: Did  any others  have met this case?

Comment: I do't use Java 8, but I solved this problem by using CMS gc algorithm. OPS :  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a use case for the G1 collector. The eden increase can be normal if you have many short-lived objects. Try setting -XX:+UseG1GC. This can collect large portions of the heap with very short STW phases.

Comment: I would use Java 8 if switching to G1.

Comment: I compared a demo program spring-mvc-showcase and my own one，the demo case also make eden increase quickly, but old space will not increase,  is it possible ways to locate something wrong in my codes or It's java 's destiny?